# Como gravar uma variável string sem quebrar a linha?

Tags: c, string, arquivo

Preciso escrever apenas na primeira linha de um arquivo, porem sempre que adiciono uma variável do tipo string essa linha é quebrada, segue o exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char name1[10];
char name2[10];
char name3[10];
char name4[10];
FILE *file;

int main(){
    printf("Nome1:");
    fgets(name1, 11, stdin);
    printf("Nome2:");
    fgets(name2, 11, stdin);
    printf("Nome3:");
    fgets(name3, 11, stdin);
    printf("Nome4:");
    fgets(name4, 11, stdin);
    file = fopen("Test.ini","a");//não pode destruir as infos ja adicionadas
    fprintf(file,"Nomes:%s,%s,%s,%s",name1,name2,name3,name4);//<- Erro aqui?
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

resultado no arquivo Test.ini:

```
Nomes:nome1
,nome2
,nome3
,nome4
```

Como deveria estar escrito no arquivo Test.ini:

```
Nomes:nome1,nome2,nome3,nome4
```

Comment: Atenção ao buffer overflow: com `char name1[10];` o que deves usar é `fgets(name1, 10, stdin);` -- eu costumo usar `fgets(name1, sizeof name1, stdin);` assim, se mudar o tamanho, não preciso de alterar duas linhas de código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `fgets()` pega o ENTER que você digitou e é isso que está quebrando a linha. Então em cada variável tem que colocar um terminador no lugar desse caractere, uma delas:

```
name1[strcspn(name1, "\n")] = 0;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/SwapNewLineTerminator.c).

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda!! Funcionou aqui =D